# Add http(s) to `<a>` tags that are missing http(s) with PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

How can I add `http(s)://` to `<a href="...">` links that do not have them with PHP? This input is coming from a lot of html input, and I want to fix only the links that are incorrect in `<a>` tags. For example, I want this

```
<html><body><a href="google.com">link</a></body></html>
```

to turn into this

```
<html><body><a href="https://google.com">link</a></body></html>
```

without the rest of the html getting changed.

In addition, how would I parse the html to find links in plain text and convert them to `<a href="...">` without changing any of the rest of the html?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to make an attempt yourself, this is not a free coding service. Once you have tried, if your stuck, post back with your attempt and any issues

Comment: I have looked up many posts on this website and modified results from those but I am completely lost and nothing works. I do not know regex very well and I cannot find a way to get this to work.

Comment: Parse the HTML then pull the `href` attribute and check if it has the protocol. Probably `^https?://` (with non `/` delimiters).

Comment: And how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do this easily by using a previous answer and using DOMDocument:

```
function addScheme($url, $scheme = 'http://'){
    return parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) === null ? $scheme . $url : $url;
}
// parse the html
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($text);
// make sure links are correct
$a_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($a_tags as $a) {
    // make sure that links start with http(s)
    $a->setAttribute('href', addScheme($a->getAttribute('href')));
}
// save parsed version
$text = $dom->saveHTML();
```